# Gerar o download png a partir de uma div?

Tags: php, jquery

Tem como fazer isso galerA? Queria que quando o usuario clicasse em : baixar png fizesse o download da imagem que tem na minha div.

```
<div class='queroquevirepng'>
<CENTER><img src='https://about.canva.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2017/02/congratulations_-banner.png' class='fundo' /><div class='logo'><br><div class='nomeEmpresa' style='position:absolute;'>DENY SISTEMAS</div></div></CENTER>
</div>
```

Comment: essa part e dificil emm...

Comment: Não altere todo o sentido da pergunta. Se quiser pode fazer outra pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Sim, é possível gerar um `png` a partir de uma div e também é possível baixar uma imagem da sua div.

Caso sua imagem seja em PNG, basta utilizar essa forma (com js puro).

```js
// Botãod de Download
var btn = document.querySelector("button");

// Captura o elemento de imagem
var img = document.querySelector(".fundo");

// Adiciona o evento para baixar a imagem.
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){

    // Cria um elemento <a> e define o href a ele
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.setAttribute("href", img.src);
    anchor.setAttribute("download", true);
    
    // Adiciona esse <a> no body do documento
    document.body.append(anchor);
    
    // Aciona o evento click
    anchor.click();
    
    // Remove o <a> do body
    document.body.removeChild(anchor);
})
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='http://www.epica.nl/epica_tss_fb_share.png' class='fundo' width="300" />
</div>

<button>Download</button>
```

> Gerar o download png a partir de uma div?

Como foi supracitado, para gerar um `png` a partir de uma div, utilize o **[html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com)**.

Comment: deu erro pra baixar amigo , nossa q mulher gata, opss..  deu erro pra baixar aqui, mas sera que aqui vai funcionar?

Comment: Poxa amigo na verdade nem funciona isso por que , eu preciso mesmo é baixar uma pagina html e transformar em png , melhor pra voces assim.

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Talvez o ajude.

Comment: Vou dar -1 pq o AP mudou a pergunta, o que não é permitido.

Comment: Ajustando a resposta eu mudo meu voto.

Comment: teste.php:24 Uncaught TypeError: document.body.append is not a function

Comment: copiei e colei e deu esse erro ae, não coloquei jquery pq é js puro mesmo. N sei o q e

Comment: deixeee usei o canvas